# Excel Charts linked to PowerPoint causing issue when Excel File is on Sharepoint (2013 online)

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2013, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint file that has a bunch of charts that are linked to an excel file that automatically update when you click on "Update Links" in PowerPoint .
Users can update the charts in the Excel file and then click a button to run a macro that opens up the powerpoint file and updates the links. However, it does no recognize that the Excel file already open is the one it should be updating from and attempts to re-open the Excel file from the sharepoint, leading to an error of "Cannot open 2 files with the same name".  The users should not have the ability to modify the Excel file, so this means saving it first and then closing the open excel file so powerpoint can then reopen it on its own is out.  So is saving the file as a different name since those changes wouldn't be saved.

Is this a known issue with PowerPoint or is there another way of getting this to work properly when pulling data from a Sharepoint location so that it recognizes the already opened Excel file IS the same file it should be opening to update the links?

I have attached the code being used:

```
    Sub updatelinksppt()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As Long
    Dim name As String

    On Error Resume Next

 With CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    .Visible = True
    .Presentations.Open "SharePoint/Path", Untitled:=msoTrue
   With .ActivePresentation
    .UpdateLinks


     For i = 1 To .Slides.Count
       For s = 1 To .Slides(i).Shapes.Count
         .Slides(i).Shapes(s).LinkFormat.BreakLink
       Next s
     Next i
     name = Sheets("User Form").Range("B4")
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Path\" & name & ".pptx"
     End With
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say powerpivot do you mean powerpoint? Are all of the graphs in one excel file or are there times where you may need to open more than one file?

Comment: @will1329 Sorry, fixed it..it is powerpoint. Basically it is set up so when users update charts in the Excel file they can then call the powerpoint file(via the macro) so it updates the charts.  It opens the powerpoint file but then when it tries to update the links it says "Cannot have two files open with the same name" because it does not recognize the already open excel file as being the one it needs to update from and tries to reopen it from Sharepoint since that is where the charts are linked to. How can I make it recognize these are in fact the same file??